# Remapping Ctrl+LWin not working

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to remap Ctrl+LWin to Shift+Alt and i tried this but it is not working: `^LWin::!Shift`. Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Have you looked at or tried using star ('*') modifiers?  Don't know if it will help, just something to look into

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm - Search for "wildcard"